# SQL Stored Procedure: If variable is not null, update statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-update

I have an update statement in a stored procedure that looks generally like this:

```
Update [TABLE_NAME]
Set XYZ=@ABC
```

Is there a good way to only trigger the update statement if the variable is not null or the value -1?

Similar to an `IF NOT EXISTS...INSERT` question.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use a T-SQL `IF`:

```
IF @ABC IS NOT NULL AND @ABC != -1
    UPDATE [TABLE_NAME] SET XYZ=@ABC
```

Take a look at the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx).

Comment: That easy huh?  Well I'm gonna go stick a fork in an electrical socket and score a dirty needle from a back alley in Atlantic City and other equally dumb things.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Jake, No worries. We all have our days. BTW, welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 29):

Another approach when you have many updates would be to use COALESCE:

```
UPDATE [DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLE_NAME]
SET    
    [ABC]  = COALESCE(@ABC, [ABC]),
    [ABCD] = COALESCE(@ABCD, [ABCD])
```

Comment: This is what I was beating my head into the desk trying to do. Much nicer looking than a whole bunch of "if-update" pairs when there's a dozen column involved.

Answer (score 5):

Yet another approach is ISNULL().

```
UPDATE [DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLE_NAME]
SET    
    [ABC]  = ISNULL(@ABC, [ABC]),
    [ABCD] = ISNULL(@ABCD, [ABCD])
```

The difference between ISNULL and COALESCE is the return type. COALESCE can also take more than 2 arguments, and use the first that is not null. I.e.

```
select COALESCE(null, null, 1, 'two') --returns 1
select COALESCE(null, null, null, 'two') --returns 'two'
```

One little note, if COALESCE hasn't argument that is not the NULL, it will throw an exception, so if you have just two arguments and both can be null - do use ISNULL.